# Trying to understand correct logic for before and after trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger

I am new to apex and have wrote a trigger on the lead object that updates fields on the record, and also creates tasks associated with the record.

I have set up the code for both of these requirements to the best of my ability but am stuck on the appropriate use of 'before/after' in the trigger.

How do I structure the code to incorporate both the before and after aspect of this requirement. Here is what I have so far.

```
trigger KeyFieldsPopulated on Lead (before insert, before update) {
    for (Lead l : Trigger.New) {
        //Create list to store key fields 
        List<String> KeyFields = new List<String>();
        KeyFields.add(l.FirstName);
        KeyFields.add(l.LastName);
        KeyFields.add(l.Email);
        KeyFields.add(l.Phone);
        KeyFields.add(l.Website);
        KeyFields.add(l.Title);

        //Create list to store key fields that have a value
        List<String> KeyFieldsPopulated = new List<String>();

        //Create a counter variable to track how many key fields have a value
        Integer counter = 0;

        //Loop through the key fields 
        for (Integer i = 0; i<KeyFields.size(); i++) {
            if (KeyFields[i]!=null) {
                KeyFieldsPopulated.add(KeyFields[i]);
                counter = counter + 1; 
            }
            l.Key_Fields__c = counter;
        }

        //Loop through the populated key fields and create a task
        if (counter >= 3) {
            for (Integer j = 0; j < KeyFieldsPopulated.size(); j++) {
                Task t = new Task();
                t.Subject = 'Verify the '+ KeyFieldsPopulated[j] + ' field';
                t.WhatId = l.Id;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy discriminant (not comprehensive, but a first pass that applies here) is "Do I need a Record Id for what I'm trying to do?" If the answer is yes, the functionality belongs in an `after` trigger, because the records in `Trigger.new` don't receive Salesforce Ids until the `after` stage.

So here:

```
    //Loop through the populated key fields and create a task
    if (counter >= 3) {
        for (Integer j = 0; j < KeyFieldsPopulated.size(); j++) {
            Task t = new Task();
            t.Subject = 'Verify the '+ KeyFieldsPopulated[j] + ' field';
            t.WhatId = l.Id;
        }

  }
```

you need to be in `after` context, because what you're doing requires the `l.Id` field to be populated in order to create a related object.

Conversely, this code

```
for (Integer i = 0; i<KeyFields.size(); i++) {
    if (KeyFields[i]!=null) {
        KeyFieldsPopulated.add(KeyFields[i]);
        counter = counter + 1;

    }
    l.Key_Fields__c = counter;
}
```

belongs in `before` context, because you're mutating fields on the object based on other fields that are populated at the time of insertion. You don't need an `Id` for that, and when you do so in `before` context, you don't need to perform DML and incur the possibility of trigger recursion.

I would strongly encourage you to consider a trigger handler framework pattern here. When working with multiple trigger events, it often becomes difficult to follow and to debug the logic when it's all in the trigger body. Adopting a good trigger framework (there are *many* available in the world of Salesforce blogs and in GitHub) helps you keep these events cleanly separated from one another by factoring your logic out into a clean, testable trigger handler class.

Comment: Thanks David, I'll do some googling to see what's out there.